# Is there a way to use a dynamic function name in Elixir from string interpolation like in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, elixir, metaprogramming, string-interpolation

I want to be able to construct a function call from a string in elixir. Is this possible? The equivalent ruby method call would be:

```
"uppercase".send("u#{:pcase}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer by @fhdhsni is perfectly correct, I’d add some nitpicking clarification.

The exact equivalent of `Kernel#send` from [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is impossible, because `Kernel#send` allows to call *private* methods on the receiver. In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), private functions do not ever exist in the compiled code.

If you meant `Kernel#public_send`, it might be achieved with [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3), as mentioned by @fhdhsni. The only correction is since the atom table is not garbage collected, and one surely wants to call an *indeed existing function*, it should be done with [`String.to_existing_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_existing_atom/1).

```rb
apply(
  String,
  String.to_existing_atom("u#{:pcase}"),
  ["uppercase"]
)
```

Also, one might use macros during the compilation stage to generate respective clauses when the list of functions to call is predictable (when it’s not, the code already smells.)

```rb
defmodule Helper do
  Enum.each(~w|upcase|a, fn fname ->
    def unquote(fname)(param),
      do: String.unquote(fname)(param)
    # or
    # defdelegate unquote(fname)(param), to: String 
  end)
end
Helper.upcase("uppercase")
#⇒ "UPPERCASE"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Elixir module and function names are atoms. You can use `apply` to call them dynamically.

```
apply(String, String.to_atom("u#{:pcase}"), ["uppercase"]) # "UPPERCASE"
```

Depending on your use case it might not be a good idea to create atoms dynamically (since the atom table is not garbage collected).